# How can I search records in a large table quickly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(product) with 5.4 million recods. If i'm using below query to get result but it's working very slow. Is there a more efficient approach?

```
SELECT sd.imageid, sd.licencetype, sd.imgcollection, sd.orientation, 
       sd.pname, sd.pcaption, sd.ptype 
FROM   (SELECT imageid 
        FROM   product 
        WHERE  productkeyword IN (SELECT primary_kwd 
                                  FROM   searchkwdmgmt 
                                  WHERE  allkwd IN ( 'IPhone' )) 
        GROUP  BY imageid 
        HAVING Count(*) = 1 
        LIMIT  0, 31) q 
       JOIN searchdetails sd 
         ON sd.imageid = q.imageid
```

Comment: Can you list the indexes on the tables in your query?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Can you show us a EXPLAIN of both select querys?

Answer (score 1):

Create Indexes on below columns

> 1.Column:allkwd Table:searchkwdmgmt
>
> 2.Column:imageid Table:searchdetails
>
> 3.Column:imageid Table:product
>
> 4.Avoid Using In Clause

Comment: how can i search multiple keyword in product table without using in clause.

Comment: use Join Instead of In Clause

Answer (score 1):

This part is bad because of the subquery

```
SELECT imageid 
FROM product 
WHERE productkeyword IN (SELECT primary_kwd 
                         FROM searchkwdmgmt 
                         WHERE allkwd IN ('IPhone'))
```

Same query should return the same data but more efficient if the indexes are correctly set.

```
SELECT
    p.imageid 
FROM
    product as p
INNER JOIN 
    searchkwdmgmt as s ON p.productkeyword = s.primary_kwd 
WHERE 
    s.allkwd IN ('IPhone')
```

Test this first before you replace it...

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of MySQL do a poor job optimizing `in` with subquery.  If you know that there is at most  one keyword match in `searchkwdmgmt` for each record in `product` you can do:

```
SELECT sd.imageid, sd.licencetype, sd.imgcollection, sd.orientation, 
       sd.pname, sd.pcaption, sd.ptype 
FROM   (SELECT p.imageid 
        FROM product p join
             searchkwdmgmt s
             on p.productkeyword = s.primary_kwd and
                s.allkwd in ( 'IPhone' )
        GROUP  BY p.imageid 
        HAVING Count(*) = 1 
        LIMIT  0, 31
       ) q join
       searchdetails sd 
       ON sd.imageid = q.imageid ;
```

If there can be more than one keyword match and there is an `id` in the `product` table, you can do:

```
SELECT sd.imageid, sd.licencetype, sd.imgcollection, sd.orientation, 
       sd.pname, sd.pcaption, sd.ptype 
FROM   (SELECT p.imageid 
        FROM product p join
             searchkwdmgmt s
             on p.productkeyword = s.primary_kwd and
                s.allkwd in ( 'IPhone' )
        GROUP  BY p.imageid 
        HAVING Count(distinct p.productid) = 1 
        LIMIT  0, 31
       ) q join
       searchdetails sd 
       ON sd.imageid = q.imageid ;
```

EDIT:

All of these versions will be faster with the following indexes:  `searchkwdmgmt(primary_kwd, allkwd)`, `product(productkeyword, imageid)`, and `searchdetails(imageid)`.

Comment: @RohitKhurana . . . Is that good or bad?  How long does the original query take?  And what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @RohitKhurana . . . Can you edit your question with this information as well as the indexes that are on the tables?